# Process Control Block(PCB) in Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system

I need to know about the data stored in Windows' Process Control Block(PCB) as well as Linux PCB. I searched the web but unfortunately I couldn't find what I was looking for. Most of links do not specify what is exactly inside the structure, they only mention the general information which must be stored in a PCB data structure. What I need is the code of both PCB structures with perhaps some documentation/explanation about their fields. I'd be thankful if somebody helps :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows, you can use Windows API to achieve this:

```
NTSTATUS WINAPI NtQueryInformationProcess(
  _In_       HANDLE ProcessHandle,
  _In_       PROCESSINFOCLASS ProcessInformationClass,
  _Out_      PVOID ProcessInformation,
  _In_       ULONG ProcessInformationLength,
  _Out_opt_  PULONG ReturnLength
```

A detailed explanation can be found here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Linux is an open-source OS, so we have more choices for achieving this, depends upon the way you want to do, e.g. reading its source code or by programming API.